# How do one convert double to string on c99? (embedded C)

Tags: c, string, embedded, double

I am collecting the digital values(integers) and doing a computation, which is of double type.  I tried displaying the values using `sprintf()` and it is only displaying the integers correctly as neither `float` nor double is being converted to string.

Is there any function from library that can be of use here to convert double -> string?

str is a character array and tempC is a double

```
   sprintf(str,"%4f",tempC );
    LCD_Position(1,0);
    LCD_PrintString(str);
```

Note:dtostrf() is not available in the system
And both sprintf and snprintf, did not work.

Comment: What about `sprintf`? How do you use it?

Comment: snprintf function well do that for you

Comment: forget to add, both sprintf and snprintf did not work.

Comment: They are supposed to work. Please provide the code you used. What did you pass to `sprintf` and what did you get? Please read [How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Gerhardh I did add the details to the question and snippet of the code.

Comment: Is that used with some microcontroller that does not support floating point types with `printf`? Maybe you need to pick another version of the C library to add to your code. Adding information about the used toolset and CPU would be useful.

Comment: Thank you, I will check that ,mean time, I really appreciate your insights and time to respond.

Comment: @Gerhardh embedded sprintf supporting floats are very large and often overflow the FLASH

Comment: What you pointed out was the issue, It was an new environment, so I had to cross check and change the build settings. I will be updating the specialization, you have any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use printf family functions on embedded targets you need to tell the compiler that you are happy to sacrifice plenty of FLASH memory to support it.

1. For AVR:
   MPLAB and GCC (probably - I do not use AVR uCs for many years) `-Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_flt -lm`
2. For ARM: `-specs=nano.specs -lc -u _printf_float`

Comment: Its solved, I missed this setting on compiler and that was the reason it was not showing up float/double, thank you!

Comment: @Rookie91 : note that if on your target the default is to exclude FP support in stdio, it is likely that it is because using FP in any event is I'll advised.  A better question perhaps would be how you might avoid FP in your code in the first instance.  It is certainly a more interesting question.

Comment: @Clifford *"It is certainly a more interesting question."* I do not think that OP wants out advice on this.